# How to stop while tesseract OCRing?

Tags: iphone, block, ocr, tesseract

im using tesseract for image OCRing in my iPhone app.
i want to stop all OCR process while its running.

here is my code:

in .h file:

```
dispatch_queue_t main;
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseract;
uint32_t *pixels;
```

in .m file:

```
- (void)processOcrAt:(UIImage *)image
{
    [self setTesseractImage:image];

    //char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
    //[self performSelector:@selector(ocrProcessingFinished:) withObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8Text]];
    //dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.awesome", 0);

    main = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(main, ^{
        tesseract->Recognize(NULL);
        char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ocrProcessingFinished:)
                               withObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8Text]
                               waitUntilDone:NO];
        delete [] utf8Text;
    });


}

-(IBAction)backPressed:(id)sender{
    dispatch_release(main);
    tesseract->Clear();
    //tesseract->End();

    delete tesseract;
    tesseract = nil;
    delete pixels;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When i tap to back button while ocr is running it crashes. because ocr is still running. How can i stop it? i couldnt find any method in tesseract.

Comment: make setTesseractImage method on main Thread using performSelectorOnMainThread...

Comment: it is still same. when ocr starts i hit the back button. tesseract is deleted in back method. thats why it crashes on tesseract->Recognize(NULL); or next line. i think i must stop/cancel the tessearact before i delete it.

Comment: is it impossible to stop/cancel the OCR process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer from tesseract form:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tesseract-ocr/1uLF4BmmmUg

I think the crux of the problem is your attempt to stop the OCR thread at a random spot in its execution yet expect the state of the Tesseract instance to be consistent. You are right to want to delete the instance otherwise you would have a memory leak but it looks like you can't do that after stopping the OCR thread abnormally. In our own iPhone app (ScanBizCards) what we do in that case is to let the OCR thread finish its work in the background even though its results will be ignored and not shown to the user. The downside is mostly that if the user starts a new scan right after aborting one we delay the start of the new scan until the previous (aborted) scan finishes.

Answer (score 1):

What about the ETEXT_DESC argument from the Recognize() function? (not sure if it was there when you wrote your answer fulberto100). It's a monitor use to tack progress, as well as cancelling it. It's used in TessBaseAPI::ProcessPage. I haven't tried it myself though.

```
ETEXT_DESC monitor;
monitor.cancel = NULL;
monitor.cancel_this = NULL;
monitor.set_deadline_msecs(timeout_millisec);
// Now run the main recognition.
failed = Recognize(&monitor) < 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This program explain the progress of page processing by Tesseract using two threads :

```
#include <baseapi.h>
#include <allheaders.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
using namespace tesseract;           

//monitorProgress will show actual progress done by tesseract
void monitorProgress();

//Here image send to extract text
void tesseractProcessing();

TessBaseAPI *api;
ETEXT_DESC *monitor = new ETEXT_DESC();

int main()
{
    //This statement will launch multiple threads in loop
    thread t1(tesseractProcessing);
    thread t2(monitorProgress);
    std::cout << "The main function execution\n";
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}

void monitorProgress()
{
    while (1)
    {        
        cout << "Current Progress :   " << monitor[0].progress << endl;      
    }
}     

void tesseractProcessing()
{
    api = new TessBaseAPI(); 
    Pix *image = pixRead("myimage.jpg");
    api->Init("tessdata", "eng", OEM_DEFAULT);      
    api->SetPageSegMode(PSM_AUTO);
    api->SetImage(image);

    api->Recognize(monitor);

    cout << "out from recognition"<<endl;

    ofstream myfile("myfile.html");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile << api->GetHOCRText(0);
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```